# Illustrator and direct selection tool. Help!

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

I was watching a tutorial on youtube on how to make a specific logo on illustrator. The guy draws a triangle with the polygon tool. He then takes the direct selection tool and grabs the uper and left corner anchor points and drags them to the right. Suddenly the corners disappear and it becomes round with only one corner left. Like a sideways water drop. I try to do this but when i drag the anchor points it just moves them. Can you help please?
THIS IS THE VIDEO: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyApsHN6ZEo&list=WL&index=21
Go to 0:50

Comment: Hi elina, welcome to GD.SE! It is kinda hard to understand what you're asking and would advise you to post an image of you're are talking about and/or post a link to the tutorial and the time of when it happens.

Comment: What version of illustrator are you using?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyApsHN6ZEo&list=WL&index=21  its on 0:50. I'm using cs6

Comment: Those are [Live corners](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/reshape-with-live-corners.html), which don't exist in cs6. There are other ways to round corners though.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the tutorial, it looks like he is using the Curvature Handles. This feature was added in Illustrator CC. By adjusting anchor points and handles in CS6, you can create the same effect, but it will require some more effort. You can refer to  [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/editing-paths.html)  page of the Adobe website to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated it in Illustrator CC. Using the direct selection tool, I selected the triangle, held shift, and selected two points.  In my version, an icon then appeared on the inside of the triangle next to the selected corners, which I clicked and dragged the icons to the side and it created the same shape.

I believe you might have to use the polygon tool to make the shape, you can use the arrow keys to adjust how many points the shape has while making it, but did not try it just making the shape with a pen tool.

[image]